# Stopwords not getting removed - solr

Tags: solr, lucene, indexing, information-retrieval

I am new to using Solr and have defined the following schema:

```
<schema name="example" version="1.5">
<fields>
    <field name="nodeId" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="_root_" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" />
    <field name="datetime" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"
        multiValued="true" />
    <field name="epochSecs" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"
                    multiValued="true" />
    <field name="subject" type="text_general" indexed="true"
        stored="true" />
    <field name="body" type="text_general" indexed="true"
        stored="true" />
    <field name="emailId" type="string" indexed="true"
        stored="true" />
    <field name="compliantFlag" type="boolean" indexed="true"
                    stored="true" />
    <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false"
        multiValued="true" />
    <field name="ngrams" type="myNGram" indexed="true" stored="false" required="false" />


</fields>
<uniqueKey>nodeId</uniqueKey>
<copyField source="datetime" dest="text" />
<copyField source="epochSecs" dest="text" />
<copyField source="subject" dest="text" />
<copyField source="body" dest="text" />
<copyField source="emailId" dest="text" />
<copyField source="compliantFlag" dest="text" />
<copyField source="text" dest="ngrams"/>

<types>
    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField"
        sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField"
                    precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0" />
    <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true"/>
    <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField"
        positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" />
            <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
    <fieldType name="myNGram" stored="false" class="solr.TextField"> 
        <analyzer type="index"> 
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/> 
            <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="5"/> 
        </analyzer> 
    </fieldType>
</types>
```

The stopwords are not getting removed from the "body" field when indexed.

Also, how do i remove the special characters like \n from the below field using solr's analysers:

```
\n \n\n\nThese are the numbers Smurfit has.  \n\nP
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StandardTokenizer` should create tokens around newlines, spaces, etc., and the stopword filter looks, at a glance, like it should be working correctly.  You should probably include a `LowercaseFilter` above your `StopwordFilter`, to prevent those matches from being case sensitive, though.

I wonder if a pertinent question might be:  What do you mean by "removed"?  Analysis only affects the *indexed* representation of the field.  It does not affect the *stored* version that you retrieve from the index in any way.  It is meant to facilitate searching, not transform the stored version of the text.  If you remove the word "the" through the filter, you should no longer get any hits on the word "the" while searching, but you will still see in when you retrieve the document from the index.

Comment: Thanks! I am able to see the text in the "body" field with stopwords (solr UI). Is that an expected behavior? When i am executing the query, i am still seeing the stopwords (though i have put the analyzers for query as well). Moreover, when i am searching using "the", i am still getting some result. So i believe, my indexing is not happening properly. Please comment!

Comment: Okay, looking closer, you are using different stop word sets ("lang/stopwords_en.txt" vs "stopwords.txt") in your `index` and `query` analyzers, which is very unusual.  If both sets are being loaded correctly and contain "the", then I would not expect the query `body:the` to return results.

Comment: what should i do in order to eliminate the stopwords from the stored version? Does solr provide any functionality for that or do i need to do that manually?

Comment: Out of the box, there really isn't any way to transform stored text through analysis, to my knowledge.  Again, that's just not what it's for.  You could leverage the Lucene tokenizers and filters to do it manually, but I believe it would need to be done manually, as a pre-processing step.